# Regular expression php after a string

Tags: php, pattern-matching

Hi I have a very long text standard and I want to take a part of a string after a standard string:

```
$string = "bla bla bla... Refer: my text /n bla bla bla";
```

I want to take the string: `my text`. Is ever after `Refer:` and before a `/n` or `/r`.
Is possible with a regular expression?
I have done this wit substr and strpos but I want to optimize my text.

Comment: `substr` and `strpos` along with their multibyte counterparts are more efficient than regular expressions.

Comment: Yes but I want to try with a pattern if is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\s signifies blank space
^ signifies except

```
preg_match('|.*Refer:\s+([^/n/r]*)|', $string, $out);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/Refer:\s+(.*?)$/i', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = "/.*Refer:(.*?)(?:\/n|\/r)/";
preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```